# KITL over serial doesn't work: WinCE 6.0

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I am trying to debug my app  using KITL.
I have built my NK.bin in Release mode

I tried to attach device:
It is showing a message ( in the debug windwo: "Show Output from : Windows CE debug"

"PB Debugger The Kernel Debugger is waiting to connect the target "

In build options:

***Check boxes checked:***

- Enable eboot space in memory
- Enable KITL
- Enable Ship build
- Run-time image can be larger than 32MB

***Target Connectivity options:***

Kernel Service Map:

- Download -> Serial ( Port: COM1, Baud: 38400, Bits: 8, Parity : NONE, Flow Control: NONE, StopBits: 1)
- Transport ->Serial ( Port: COM1, Baud: 38400, Bits: 8, Parity : NONE, Flow Control: NONE, StopBits: 1)
- Debugger -> kdStub

***Core Service Settings:***

Download Image:

- Never (jump to image only )

KITL Settings:

- Enable KITL on device boot ( CHECKED ).

Another question:
(1) Do I need to open hyper terminal on COM1 ?

Answer (score 1):

So am I correct that you are trying to use serial KITL and noth ethernet?  Ethernet is by far the most common usage (I've not seen anyone do serial KITL in years) and I don't know if I've ever seen a BSP that shipped set up for serial out of the box, so it's likely going to require some plumbing on your part.

Have you implemented the [KITL serial driver functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa447187.aspx)?  Did you set up the serial initialization during [OEMKitlInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478773.aspx)?  You might need to adjust/implement other [KITL functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478989%28v=WinEmbedded.60%29.aspx) depending on how your serial port is implemented as well.

The first step, I think, would be to contact the device OEM and see fi they have any pointers or experince getting this working on your target platform.  That could save you a load of time and headache if they have.